# Unparsable JSON String exception

Tags: json, spring, string, unit-testing, spring-mvc

All tests from get methods work,
and this line works fine for them:

```
    .andExpect(content().json(ow.writeValueAsString(orders.get(0))))
```

Here is the code:
Test setUp

```
    @Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private OrderService orderService;

private List<OrderDTO> orders;
private String ordersJson;
ObjectWriter ow;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws JsonProcessingException {
    orders = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        orders.add(new OrderDTO.OrderDTOBuilder("test"+i, i*100)
                .build());
    }
    ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    ordersJson = ow.writeValueAsString(orders);
}
```

Test that fails:

```
    @Test
@DisplayName("POST /orders test - order saved with status 200")
@WithMockUser(roles = "PUBLISHER")
void saveNewOrder() throws Exception {
    Mockito.doReturn(orders.get(0)).when(orderService).saveOrder(any(),any(),any(),any());

    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/orders")
                    .content(ow.writeValueAsString(orders.get(0)))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(content().json(ow.writeValueAsString(orders.get(0))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
}
```

Tested Controller method:

```
    @PostMapping("")
public OrderDTO saveNewOrder(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderData,
                             @RequestBody List<Long> processes,
                             @RequestBody Long clientId,
                             @RequestBody Long deliveryId)
        {
    return orderService.saveOrder(orderData, processes, clientId, deliveryId);
}
```

And here is the console message:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unparsable JSON string: 

at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:56)
at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare.compareJSON(JSONCompare.java:50)
at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare.compareJSON(JSONCompare.java:125)
at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:415)
at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:394)
at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:336)
at org.springframework.test.util.JsonExpectationsHelper.assertJsonEqual(JsonExpectationsHelper.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers.lambda$json$9(ContentResultMatchers.java:215)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
at eu.mrndesign.matned.metalserwisproductionrest.controller.OrderControllerTest.saveNewOrder(OrderControllerTest.java:166)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options from what you have posted.

option 1: Relax your API with updating to `required=false`

```
@PostMapping("")
public OrderDTO saveNewOrder(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderData,
                             @RequestBody(required=false) List<Long> processes,
                             @RequestBody(required=false) Long clientId,
                             @RequestBody(required=false) Long deliveryId)
        {
    return orderService.saveOrder(orderData, processes, clientId, deliveryId);
}
```

Option 2: Add all required items in your test. this is a snippet and now real code.

```
MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/orders")
                    .content("send all the required data with orderData, processes, clientId and deliveryId"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have chosen option 1. Works perfectly!